# integrals of exponential functions over the real axis

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to evaluate the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-\sqrt{1+x^2})dx?
$$

I intend to change the variable $x$ to $\tan t$ but failed... How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you make the change of variable $u=\sqrt{1+x^2}$ you get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-\sqrt{1+x^2})\:dx&=2\int_0^\infty \exp(-\sqrt{1+x^2})\:dx\\\\
&=2\int_1^\infty \frac{u}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}e^{-u}\:du
\end{align}
$$ and the latter integral is a representation of the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html) $( eq.(7))$ giving

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-\sqrt{1+x^2})\:dx=2K_1(1).
> $$

You may find many properties of that function [here](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_374.htm) (power series expansions, asymptotics, differential equations, approximations, generating function, integral representations...).

Comment: I took the liberty of correcting the typo.  The square root term had been written $\sqrt{1-u^2}$, which of course rendered the integral purely imaginary.  I hope you don't mind my doing so.

Comment: @Dr.MV No problem, thanks to have corrected my typo!